# Remap right up arrow to shift does not work as expected

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I've read the several questions regarding remapping keys and I found that to remap my right up arrow to a shift key would require:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 111 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R'
```

or

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 111 = Shift_R'
```

Giving me in fact two right shifts

However in Ubuntu 20.04 on my Tuxedo laptop, this has the effect of deactivating the up arrow feature not to remap it to shift.

So typing right up arrow u gives me a u.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a modifier requires extra steps,
as [ArchWiki's xmodmap page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Reassigning_modifiers_to_keys_on_your_keyboard)
documents.

To remap the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow to a <kbd>Shift</kbd>, create the file `mymapfile` with contents:

```
clear Shift
add Shift = Shift_L Shift_R Up
keycode 111 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
```

Now issue

```
xmodmap mymapfile
```

Comment: Amazing!

Thanks very much, this is really valuable information..

Just what I wanted, GREAT